# How can I transfer python datetime to discord DateTimeCord?

Tags: python, datetime, discord.py

hmm... how can I turn a python DateTime obj to discord DateTimeCord `(<t: ? :R>)` ?

(I can transfer that using [this](https://datetimecord.rauf.wtf/) by myself but I want to do this thing with a bot)

I had tried `.toordinal()` but that is not correct...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The number in the middle is the epoch timestamp of your `Datetime` instance.

```py
py_dt = datetime.now()  # Whatever your current datetime is
epoch = round(py_dt.timestamp())  # Timestamp returns a float so round it
disc_dt = f"<t:{epoch}:R>"
```

You could've also gotten that from the [Discord docs](https://discord.com/developers/docs/reference#message-formatting) though (last two lines).